# How can I make Kaboom.js Sprite Animations Repeat?

Tags: animation, sprite

I'm using Kaboom.js to make some games and while it's easy to move players about, I've been stuck for a while on getting sprite sheet animations to work. I've kind of managed it, as you can see in the code here, using setInterval, and messing about with the values to make my particular 7 step animation (a dino animation from [Open Game Art](https://opengameart.org/content/free-dino-sprites) which I made into a sprite sheet using the Codeshack [image to sprite generator](https://codeshack.io/images-sprite-sheet-generator/) but I can't help thinking there must be a better way?

```
kaboom({
  global: true,
  width: 320,
  height: 240,
  scale: 2,
  debug: true,
  clearColor: [0, 0, 1, 1],
});

loadRoot("img/");
loadSprite("dino", "spritesheet.png", {
  sliceX: 8,
  sliceY: 1,
  anims: {
    idle: { from: 1, to: 1 },
    run: { from: 1, to: 7 },
  },
});

const player = add([
  sprite("dino", {
    animSpeed: 2,
    frame: 1,
  }),
  pos(width() * 0.5, height() * 0.5),
  origin("center"),
  scale(1),
]);


let myInterval;

function animateR() {
  myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    player.play("run");
    player.move(1000, 0);
  }, 100);
}
function animateL() {
  myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    player.play("run");
    player.move(-1000, 0);
  }, 100);
}

keyPress("right", () => {
  player.scale.x = 1;
  animateR();
});

keyPress("left", () => {
  player.scale.x = -1;
  animateL();
});

keyDown("x", () => {
  player.move(0, -10);
});

keyRelease("left", () => {
  clearInterval(myInterval);
});

keyRelease("right", () => {
  clearInterval(myInterval);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another method that integrates JSON and a file format created by Aseprite. The method is outlined in the Replit docs in their Mario tutorial. Here is the link:
[Build Mario with Kaboom](https://docs.replit.com/tutorials/32-build-mario-with-kaboom)

The tutorial contains pictures and also contains additional sprite-related information. Aseprite is available on GitHub, if you find you would like to generate JSON files for sprite sheets. Here's how it works:

1. Import your sprite sheet into Aseprite. This works best on a sheet that has the same sized elements in a grid. I use .png format.
2. Add loops and tags to the file information.
3. Export the sprite sheet as a JSON file. Be sure to change the type from "Hash" to "Array" in the dropdown. Otherwise Kaboom.js will throw an error.
4. Add your sprite sheet and your JSON file to your project. If the loops and tags were properly added to the Aseprite project, the JSON file will contain the information you need to use animations in Kaboom.js.

The Mario character data that is used in the tutorial provides an excellent example of how it looks. When you open the .ase file that is included in that asset pack for "Mario", you can see the tags in the timeline. (You may have to turn the timeline on in the settings.)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @tjheslin1 Thank you for your feedback. I really want to make my own tutorial on the matter, because the tutorial I've linked doesn't actually explain using Aseprite. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
//License: MIT, free software, Mgr. Jan Hrubos, kaboom.js example
// Init with some options (check out #KaboomOpt for full options list)
kaboom({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    font: "sinko",
    global:true,
    background: [ 0, 0, 255, ],
    canvas: document.querySelector("#mycanvas"),
    debug:true
})


scene("begin",()=>{
    function addButton(txt, p, f) {

        const btn = add([
            text(txt,{size:48}),
            pos(p),
            area(),
            scale(1),
            origin("center"),
        ])
    
        btn.onClick(f)
    
        btn.onUpdate(() => {
            if (btn.isHovering()) {
                const t = time() * 10
                btn.color = rgb(
                    wave(0, 255, t),
                    wave(0, 255, t + 2),
                    wave(0, 255, t + 4),
                )
                btn.scale = vec2(1.2)
            } else {
                btn.scale = vec2(1)
                btn.color = rgb()
            }
        })
    
    }
    
    addButton("Start CD Man", vec2(width()/2, height()/2), () => go("level1"))
    onKeyPress("space", () => go("level1"))
})
go("begin")

loadSprite("bck", "./assets/images/bck.png")
loadSprite("ghost", "./assets/images/ghost.png")
loadSprite("diamond", "./assets/images/diamond.png")
loadSprite("star", "./assets/images/star.png")
loadSprite("wall", "./assets/images/wall.png")
loadSprite('pacman', './assets/images/pacmanMap.png', {
    sliceX: 8,
    sliceY: 1,
    anims: {
        runRight: { from: 0, to: 1 },
        runLeft: { from: 2, to: 3 },
        runDown: { from: 4, to: 5 },
        runUp: { from: 6, to: 7 }
    }
})

loadSound("shoot", "./assets/sounds/shoot.mp3")
loadSound("kling", "./assets/sounds/kling.mp3")


scene("level1",()=>{


    const score = add([
        text("Score: 0", {
            size: 28, // 48 pixels tall
            width: 320, // it'll wrap to next line when width exceeds this value
            font: "sink", // there're 4 built-in fonts: "apl386", "apl386o", "sink", and "sinko"
        },),
        pos(10, 5),
        { value: 0 },
    ])


    const SPEED=80

    const bck2 = add([
        sprite("bck"),
        origin("center"),
        pos(width()/2,height()/2),
        z(-100),       
    ])

    const map = [[
        // Design the level layout with symbols
        "====================",
        "=        =         =",
        "=        =   ****  =",
        "=        =   ****  =",
        "=        =====     =",
        "=                  =",
        "=    ********      =",
        "=========          =",
        "=       =          =",
        "=  ***  =          =",
        "=  ***  =    ****  =",
        "=  ***  =    ****  =",
        "=  ***  =    ****  =",
        "=       =    ****  =",
        "=    ====          =",
        "=                  =",
        "=          =========",
        "=          *****   =",
        "=          *****   =",
        "====================",
    ]]

    const levelCfg={
    // The size of each grid
    width: 40,
    height: 30,
    "=": () => [
        sprite("wall"),
        area(),     
        scale(0.5),
        solid(),
        z(-90),
        "wall",
    ],
    "*": () => [
        sprite("star"),
        area(),     
        scale(1),
        solid(),
        "star",
    ],
    }
    const level1 = addLevel(map[0],levelCfg)
    
    const player = add([
        sprite('pacman', {
            animSpeed: 1,
            frame: 0
        }),
        origin("center"),
        pos(100,100),
        z(-90),
        body(),
        gravity(0),
        area(),
        "player"       
    ])

    const ghost1 = add([
        sprite('ghost'),
        origin("center"),
        pos(400,400),
        z(-90),
        body(),
        gravity(0),
        area(),
        "enemy"       
    ])
    
    dir=1
    loop(0.1,()=>{
        ghost1.move(0,dir*SPEED*10)
    })

    ghost1.onCollide("wall",()=>{
        dir=-dir
    })

    ghost1.onCollide("star",()=>{
        dir=-dir
    })

    player.onCollide("star", (star) => {
        destroy(star)
        score.value += 1
        score.text = "Score:" + score.value
        play("kling")
        if (score.value==54){
            go("begin")
        }
    })

    

    let myInterval;
    const intervalTime=300

    function animateR() {
        clearInterval(myInterval)
    myInterval = setInterval(() => {
        player.play("runRight");
    }, intervalTime);
    }

    function animateL() {
        clearInterval(myInterval)
        myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            player.play("runLeft");
        }, intervalTime);
        }

    function animateD() {
            clearInterval(myInterval)
            myInterval = setInterval(() => {
                player.play("runDown");
            }, intervalTime);
        }

    function animateU() {
            clearInterval(myInterval)
            myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            player.play("runUp");
            }, intervalTime);
        }

    onKeyPress("right", () => {
        animateR()
    })

    onKeyPress("left", () => {
        animateL()
    })

    onKeyPress("down", () => {
        animateD()
    })

    onKeyPress("up", () => {
        animateU()
    })

    let Risdown=false
    let Lisdown=false
    let Uisdown=false
    let Disdown=false

    onKeyDown("right",()=>{
        Risdown=true
        if (Lisdown==false && Uisdown==false && Disdown==false){
            player.move(SPEED, 0)
        }
            })

    onKeyDown("left", () => {
        Lisdown=true
        if (Risdown==false && Uisdown==false && Disdown==false){
          player.move(-SPEED, 0)  
        }
    })

    onKeyDown("down", () => {
        Disdown=true
        if (Lisdown==false && Risdown==false && Uisdown==false){
             player.move(0, SPEED)
        }
    })

    onKeyDown("up", () => {
        Uisdown=true
        if (Lisdown==false && Risdown==false && Disdown==false){
            player.move(0, -SPEED)
        } 
    })

    onKeyRelease("right",()=>{
        Risdown=false
    })

    onKeyRelease("left",()=>{
        Lisdown=false
    })

    onKeyRelease("up",()=>{
        Uisdown=false
    })

    onKeyRelease("down",()=>{
        Disdown=false
    })

    onKeyDown("space", () => {
        clearInterval(myInterval)
    })
    
    onKeyPress("f", (c) => {
        fullscreen(!isFullscreen())
    })

    
    

    player.onCollide("enemy",(enemy)=>{
        destroy(enemy)
        shake(20)
        play("shoot")
    })

})
```